# Rails 4: Save Checkbox Results to Serialized Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox, form-helpers

I have a `Campaign` model with a `channel` column. This `channel` will store a `serialized` array of chosen results via checkboxes.

Here's the model..

**app/models/campaign.rb**

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
    serialize :channels, Array
end
```

**app/controllers/compaigns_controller.rb**

```
class CampaignsController < ApplicationController
      def index
        @campaigns = Campaign.all.order("created_at DESC")
      end

      def new
        @campaign = Campaign.new
      end

      def create
        @campaign = Campaign.new(campaign_params)


        if @campaign.save

            zip = Uploadzip.find(params[:uploadzip_id])
            zip.campaign = @campaign
            zip.save

            flash[:success] = "Campaign Successfully Launched!"
            redirect_to @campaign
        else
            flash[:error] = "There was a problem launching your Campaign."
            redirect_to new_campaign_path
        end
      end

      def show
        @campaign = Campaign.includes(:program, :uploadzip, :channel, :plan, :uploadpdfs).find(params[:id])
      end

  private

      def campaign_params
        params.require(:campaign).permit(:name, :comment, :channel, :plan_id, :program_id, :campaign_id, uploadpdf_ids: [])
      end
end
```

The part of the form with checkboxes..

**views/campaigns/_target.rb**

```
<%= form_for @campaign, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>

   ...

<label class="right-inline">
   <%= f.label :channel, "Distribution Channel", class: "right-label" %>
</label>

<ul class="channel-list">
    <% ["Folder", "Fax", "Email"].each do |channel| %>

    <li><%= check_box_tag :channel, channel %> <%= channel %>
        <% end %></li>
</ul>

...

<% end %>
```

I'm having problems saving these results inside the Campaign object.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: first I think you `each` loop is wrong. In each loop you create a `<li>` and you have only one `</li>` out of the loop.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First of all, you mentioned that the column name is `channel`, but you have used its plural version in `Campaign` model. Since you are planning to save array of channels in this column, I would suggest you change the name of the column in the database to `channels`. All the code below assumes that you will change the database column to `channels`.

Since you are serializing the `channels` attribute to an `Array` and your form will send that parameter as an array to the controller, you will need to update your `campaign_params` method accordingly.

```
def campaign_params
  params.require(:campaign).permit(:name, :comment, :plan_id, :program_id, :campaign_id, uploadpdf_ids: [], channels: [])
end
```

Now, the relevant part of your `@campaign` form should look like this:

```
<ul class="channels-list">
  <% ["Folder", "Fax", "Email"].each do |channel| %>
    <li><%= check_box_tag "campaign[channels][]", channel, @campaign.channels.include?(channel), id: "campaign_channels_#{channel}" %> <%= channel %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

**Explanation**

First argument in `check_box_tag` is `name` attribute of the tag. Second is `value` attribute. Third is boolean value to tell whether the checkbox will be checked or not when rendered initially. This will be helpful in `edit` form to show current selections.

Note that I am providing `id` attribute explicitly. If we don't do that, all three checkboxes will have the same id (derived from their names), which would not be valid HTML because id should not be repeated.

Generated HTML should look like this:

```
<li><input type="checkbox" name="campaign[channels][]" id="campaign_channels_Folder" value="Folder" /> Folder</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="campaign[channels][]" id="campaign_channels_Fax" value="Fax" /> Fax</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="campaign[channels][]" id="campaign_channels_Email" value="Email" /> Email</li>
```

The `controller` will see `channels` param as an array of selected values.

This should work both for New and Edit forms.

Comment: This works! Thank you for the great response. Very thorough and easy to understand. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Words, solution code, explanation of code. Also polite. Can SO please have more of you. 0/

Comment: Do you have a nice solution for the scenario where the value is always present, it's just a matter of "true" or "false"?