# How to Save Multiple Checkbox Values to a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-6

I use Rails 6.1 and the gem simple_form.
I want save value of multiple checkbox in an object (string serialized or array). i don't find a simple solution.

table

```
    class CreateSpots < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :spots do |t|

      t.string :wind_direction

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for (spot) do |f| %> 
  <%= f.input :wind_direction, as: :check_boxes, collection: Spot::DIRECTION %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

model

```
  class Spot < ApplicationRecord
  DIRECTION = ['N','NW','W','SW','S','SE','E','NE']
  end
```

After submit the form, the output of `wind_direction` is Nil

ideally, i look for a string, i work with this format actually.

```
wind_direction: "[\"W\", \"NW\", \"N\", \"NE\", \"E\"]",
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Maybe this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813648/rails-4-save-checkbox-results-to-serialized-array) help

Comment: The code you shared looks fine, but are you accessing the params properly in your create action?

  `Spot.create(wind_direction: params[:spot][:wind_direction])`

Comment: Thanks @Spikie, it was close to my need.

Comment: Thanks @DillonHafer, yes params was good

Answer (score 0):

i've find a solution, i've create a join table like in this example. It seem a reliable way to handle check-box

https://www.sitepoint.com/save-multiple-checkbox-values-database-rails/

and i serialize the result with `.to_json`